# Code for android that would use a compass to point to a specific Longatude and Latatude?

Tags: android, compass-geolocation

I'm brand new to coding apps. I have an idea. Does anyone have a code snip for pointing the user towards a pre programed geographical point?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the bearing between two locations by the following code:

```
double x = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(lng1-lng2);
double y = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lng1-lng2);
double bearing = Math.atan2(x, y);
```

The problem is, that you need know the current heading of the phone, too. The codesnipped only calculates the bearing relative to the geographic north.

You could use my [CompassAssistant](https://github.com/klein-artur/Simple-Android-Compass-Assistant) class. It has the bearing functionality you need. The howto is in the readme. Do not hesitate to ask me if you need help.

If you wan´t to do it by yourself: I have descriped the solution for a compass in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38874786/1640012). Simple add the negative value the compass gives you to the value you got by calculation the bearing with the code above.

Hope this helps you.